# Hybris upgrade returning a different response

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

We have recently upgraded our system to the latest patch of Hybris 1808. We noticed that the cmsoccaddon has been moved into a full extension by SAP - so we have defined a dependency from our webservices extension onto this new extension. Since doing this, the content of our /pages endpoint has changed. Specifically, before we patched, custom properties in CMS components were added directly into the JSON representation of the CMS component (example 1 below). After we patched, custom properties are being displayed (in a different structure) within the "otherProperties" property (example 2 below).

```
Example 1
{
  "uid": "SomeCustomCmsComponent1",
  "typeCode": "SomeCustomCmsComponent",
  ...
  "customProperty": "customValue"
}
```

Example 2

```
{
  "uid": "SomeCustomCmsComponent1",
  "typeCode": "SomeCustomCmsComponent",
  ...
  "otherProperties": [{ "key": "customProperty", value: {type: "string", value: "customValue"}}]
}
```

Question:

1. Was declaring a dependency on the new cmsoccaddon extension the correct thing to do?
2. Does Spartacus support referencing the properties in "otherProperties" in a transparent way -- or do we have to do additional conversion on the Spartacus side?
3. Do we need to perform customization/configuration in Hybris to move these custom properties out of the "otherProperties" attribute, directly onto the JSON root of the CMS component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was an issue on our side with a previous customization of the cmsoccaddon.